# Что такое malloc() ?

Tags: c, malloc

Зачем это нужно и как использовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В C/C++ это функция для выделения памяти (**m**emory **alloc**ation).

```
char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
```

Выделяет 5 * sizeof(char) байт памяти.

 Не совсем понял при чем метка csharp, насколько знаю в шарпах этой функции нет, но если я ошибаюсь, то подписываюсь под вопросом =)

Comment: мне надо использовать в шарпе библиотеку С и функция malloc() прописывается. Я в этом ужасно плохо разбираюсь. А как знать сколько байт памяти надо выделять?
pin = fftwf.malloc(n*8);    здесь как я понял не 5, а 8. почему 8?

Comment: 5 было просто примером. Сколько памяти нужно выделять должен знать непосредственно разработчик. В си, к примеру, если нужно считать файл в строку, то вычисляется размер файла в байтах и выделяется необходимое количество памяти.

Comment: А что, в примере по использованию fftw нет комментариев? Там же написано про malloc: "unmanaged array". И malloc там альтернатива Pinned-массивам c#, хотя, возможно, те и не выровнены (misaligned)

Comment: Провал... Действительно же все расписано подробно, или Vezd'у нужен перевод?..

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define SomeType double
void main()
{
    unsigned int ArraySize;
    scanf("%u",&ArraySize);
    SomeType *t=(SomeType*)malloc(sizeof(SomeType)*ArraySize);
    /*
        do something
    */
    free(t);
}
```

вот пример на С работы с malloc и не забывайте, что необходимо освобождать память.