# Поясните мне строку кода, пожалуйста

Tags: c++, c

```
char *str = (char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Раcпишите что тут делает каждая команда)

Comment: Почти дубликат ) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16215/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-malloc

Comment: Что вы называете "командой"? Сколько "команд" вы видите в приведенной строчке?

Answer (score 6):

Выделение памяти на `(n+1)*размер символьного типа` , каст к указателю на символьный тип и инициализация переменной `str` типа указатель на символьный тип.

Comment: Тут нет никакого "присвоения".

Comment: @AnT лучше написать инициализация или как?

Comment: Это, разумеется, именно инициализация.

Comment: @Andrey: Это где вы такое взяли? Ничего подобного в С и С++ нет. Такой синтаксис нигде и никогда не вызывал никакого "присвоения". Даже в классическом C++ никакой "дефолтной инициализации и присвоения" здесь не было бы, не говоря уже о современном С++, который гарантирует полную эквивалентность исходного и вашего варианта. Запомните: в *объявлениях* с инициализатором *всегда* выполняется *инициализация*, и *никогда* не выполняется "присвоение".

Comment: @AnT да, вы правы, посмотрел оба варианта - mov dword ptr [a],0Ah и там и там, но это только для встроенных типов

Comment: @Andrey: Абсолютно не верно! Ни в коем случае. Копирующая инициализация = копирующая инициализация. Для классов это инициализация конструктором копирования. Еще раз: **никогда** копирующая инициализация (или какая-либо еще инициализация) не будет использовать присваивание.

Comment: @Andrey: Пытаться анализировать концептуальные свойства языка путем смотрения на сгенерированный машинный код - совершенно бессмысленное занятие.

Comment: @AnT - но тоже занятие